# I'm trying to make a random number generator for my game and assign a integer to it so i can use it later but give me a error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code:

```
public class Random
{
    public void pipeSpawn()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);
    }
}
```

I get an error underlined under Next saying my method doesn't contain a definition for Next?

Note: Sorry if my explanation is bad I'm not great at explaining / coding.

Comment: You need to specify `System.Random`, because UnityEngine also contains a definition for Random (static class).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to use the `Random` class as defined in .NET but I suspect the `include` is pointing to the one in **Unity**.

Unity:

[`Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html)

> Easily generate random data for games.
> This static class provides several easy game-oriented ways of generating pseudorandom numbers.

Unity's `Random` has no `Next` method.  Also it is a `static` class so you don't `new` it.

In your case just use Unity's:

```
int num = (int) Random.Range(1f, 9f);
```